# How to use a linux expect script to enter answer a prompt for password

Tags: linux, command-line, expect

I am having some trouble writing a script that will launch my forticlient vpn command line client and send my password when it is prompted.  Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set loadme "./forticlientsslvpncli --server myvpnserver --vpnuser theuser
eval spawn $loadme
expect "Password for VPN: "
send "password\r"
```

However, it still prompts for the vpn password.  I am sure it is something simple and I am pretty new to linux scripting, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: missing a closing quote in the `set loadme` line. Also, add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script -- expect will show you if the password prompt is being matched.

Comment: The missing closing quote was a typo on here, but thanks for pointing it out.  Adding `exp_internal 1` (which is the same as `#!/var/bin/expect -d`) solved my problem.  For those that might not know `-d` provides debugging output so I quickly realized the prompt was not being matched. I wish I could mark your answer as the correct, however I will up vote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comment I got from glenn jackman I was able to figure out that the password prompt was not being matched.  I changed my first line to `#!/var/bin/expect -d`   which provided the necessary debugging output to find out the problem and fix it.

Thanks Glenn!

Answer (score 17):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
cd /usr/local/forticlientsslvpn
spawn ./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server myhost:10443 --vpnuser myuser
expect "Password for VPN:" {send -- "mypassword\r"}
expect "to this server? (Y/N)\r" {send -- "y\r"}

expect eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code syntax could be wrong or given password could be wrong. So you can try it on expect prompt - line by line to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `forticlientsslvpn_cli` with [Expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to feed in the password.

A complete solution available here:

https://gist.github.com/azizasm/e216bc47b54f5b68405f3c8f8b832e8a

Note: this solution will auto reconnect the if the VPN get disconnected.